# can't print certain data from NY times api to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I can get the API from NY times but can't seem to print the what I want to HTML.  I consoled log the mbutton and it transfers the proper value to the headline picked.  Since I am a student can you explain where I went wrong? and why your steps correct it.

What I'm trying to do is display an image, URL and a headline.  After the user picks a headline subject from a dropdown menu.

I've searched youtube and multiple of jquery API's articles.  I am also doing https://medium.freecodecamp.org

```
$(function() {
  $("body").on("change", "#mbtton", function() {
    headLinePicked = $("#mbtton").val();
    counter = 0;
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: website + headLinePicked + apikey,
      dataType: "json"
    });
  });
  console.log("before append");
  (function(data) {
    do {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("in append");
      $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].title).innerHTML;
      $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].multimedia[0].url)
    .innerHTML;
      $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].url).innerHTML;
      counter++;
      console.log(counter);
    } while (counter <= 12);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the data to post to HTML. But, it is not showing up in the HTML.

I added "success: function(apiresult) to the ajax.  With the following

```
    do {
         console.log(data);
         console.log("in append");
         $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].title).innerHTML;
         $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].multimedia[0].url)
.innerHTML;
         $("body").append("#printToHtml" + data.results[counter].url).innerHTML;
  counter++;
         console.log(counter);
         } while (counter <= 12);
```